# Symfony base url proxypass

Tags: apache, symfony, assets, proxypass

My symfony website is behind a proxypass, here is my proxypass:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain.dev
    ProxyPreserveHost on

    # setup the proxy
    <Proxy *>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass /foo http://10.0.3.22/foo
    ProxyPassReverse /foo http://10.0.3.22/foo

</VirtualHost>
```

Because mydomain.dev is another website.

When I open http://mydomain.dev/foo, my symfony website rendering but all assets return 404 Not Found because it try to get from url http://mydomain.dev/css/... instead of http://mydomain.dev/foo/css/...

Same problem if I remove /foo from my proxypass:

```
ProxyPass /foo http://10.0.3.22/
ProxyPassReverse /foo http://10.0.3.22/
```

I want all assets, all routes, and all links in my symfony to be prefixed by /foo, any configuration for that ? Symfony or Apache config ?

Thanks

--

Symfony 2.5.6 | Apache 2.4

Comment: What does your debugging console say? Also, just to confirm, it is still not working when removing foo in the web server config?

Answer (score 0):

Self-answer:

### Parameters

I added the prefix in my parameters:

```
#parameters.yml
parameters:
  website_prefix: foo
```

### Routing

And added prefix to all my routes like this:

```
#app/config/routing_base.yml
twig:
    globals:
        asset_base: "/%website_prefix%"
login:
    path:   /login
    defaults:  { _controller: 
    ezpublish.security.controller:loginAction }
login_check:
    path:   /login_check
logout:
    path:   /logout

_ezpublishRoutes:
    resource: "@EzPublishCoreBundle/Resources/config/routing/internal.yml"

_ezpublishLegacyRoutes:
    resource: "@EzPublishLegacyBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"

_ezpublishRestRoutes:
    resource: "@EzPublishRestBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   %ezpublish_rest.path_prefix%

_ezpublishRestOptionsRoutes:
    resource: "@EzPublishRestBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix: %ezpublish_rest.path_prefix%
    type: rest_options

_liip_imagine:
    resource: "@LiipImagineBundle/Resources/config/routing.xml"

#_ezpublishDemoRoutes:
#    resource: "@eZDemoBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
```

And

```
#app/config/routing.yml
_routing_prefixed:
    resource: "routing_base.yml"
    prefix:   %website_prefix%
```

### Assets

And for my assets, I used a twig global variable:

```
#app/config/config.yml
twig:
    globals:
        assets_base: "%website_prefix%"
```

And in my twigs

```
{% stylesheets filter='?yui_css, cssrewrite' output='css/main.css'
        'bundles/mybundle/css/bootstrap.css'
        'bundles/mybundle/css/cs-select.css'
        'bundles/mybundle/css/cs-skin-border.css'
        'bundles/mybundle/css/video-js.css'
        'bundles/mybundle/css/owl.carousel.css'
        'bundles/mybundle/css/owl.theme.css'
        'bundles/mybundle/css/main.css'
        'bundles/mybundle/css/custom.css'
    %}
        <link href="{{ assets_base }}/{{ asset_url }}" rel="stylesheet">
    {% endstylesheets %}
```

And it works fine :)